# Authentication error when roaming to different AP

Tags: authentication, networking, wifi

I'm trying to setup the internet at my home. I have an edgerouter x as main router and I want to connect 3 wifi access points to it, all with the same SSID/password so I can roam through my house without having to connect to a different network. The solution seemed simple, setup AP with DHCP and set the other two APs in bridge mode, disable DHCP, set the right SSID and password and done.

Everything goes fine for the AP with DHCP and 1 other AP, but whenever I add the third AP, I can't connect to the wifi, it just keeps on authenticating. 
I tried looking up the problem of course, what I found that it is probably due to different security settings on the different APs. However, I can't seem to find where/how to match these settings to resolve the issue.

Could anyone help me out?

The router that has the problem is the TP-Link Archer C7. The one with DHCP enabled is the Netgear WAC104 and the AP that does work is the TP-link AP200.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (one root AP and one bridged; i couldn't get around Authetication error on Windows 10 and Android when trying to connect to bridged AP) what partially worked was in the android settings - wifi - WPS Push Button and when prompt to push WPS button on AP i did so and voila. Android suddenly connected and Windows 10 as well (did nothing additional there). Just to clarify - AP is TP-Link. ANd what dodn't work was adding MAC address as allowed to MAC filtering. Didn't seem to have any security differernces since i use almost all settings on default and two APs were same model and firmware. It worked partially because after a few minutes tried to connect to bridged AP but had to repeat WPS steps in order to work.